# Composer does not update drush

Tags: drush

```
composer global update
```

> Changed current directory to /home/ckosloff/.composer Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
>   require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable
>   set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - drush/drush dev-master requires codegyre/robo ~1.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by codegyre/robo[1.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - drush/drush dev-master requires codegyre/robo ~1.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by codegyre/robo[1.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].

The above is what I get when running `composer global update`.

Steps taken:

1. I updated composer to latest build via self-update
2. I added the line `minimum stability:"dev"` to composer.json

Drush is not getting updated to the latest version.
How can I solve this?

Comment: either install **codegyre/robo ~1.0.0-beta1** OR  run `composer require drush/drush:~8` and use the stable release of Drush.

Comment: THe json syntax was wrong, as the error suggested after I added "minimum-stabilty":"dev", the line is correct , but he json syntax was not, I got support in #drupal-support, many thanks to user mchelen. I also learned about json syntax, it has its own peculiarities.